# File Constructor can not read file in RestFull webservice

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
File jarFile = new File("src/test/java/Draft.jar");
if ((jarFile).exists()) {

System.out.println("Jar file exists");

} 
else {

   System.out.println("Jar file not exists");

}
```

jar is present in that location but it's not run properly every time it prints "Jar file not exists"

Comment: Normal java runtime won't be able to access things under `src/test`. Put the JAR anywhere under `src/java/resources` and it should work.

Comment: Please format your code as code.... and yes, you need to add a bit more context/explanation as code alone good question form does not (to say with Yoda).

Comment: Runtime environment doesn't contain your file in expected path. File is located from execution folder. Add debug print like this to find out your one: System.out.println(Paths.get(".").getParent());

Comment: That's a relative file path to your current directory. Where are you running this code? And what does it have to do with Spring MVC?

Answer (score 1):

You need avoid put files inside `src/test` location,since when you compile your code,it might clean the files

For your question,two ways to debug it:

a. make the jar file in another location,not `src/test`,you can change to `src/resources`,in fact,you had better not put file inside `src` folder. Also you need to make sure the file path is correct,sometimes you need to add `.. /` to get the right path

b. use `absolute path` instead of `relative path`,such as below:

```
File jarFile = new File("D://Draft.jar");
```

Comment: Tried First way but got same result.

Comment: @sujitkumbhar change to another folder outside `src`